# What is the LDAP schema syntax to specify list of allowed attribute values?

Tags: ldap, schema, ldif, opendj

I am new to OpenDJ and LDAP and I want to know what is the LDAP Schema syntax to specify an attribute can have only one of the few values?
For example, an `User` object has an attribute called `status` that can have only one of these values: `Active`, `In-Active`.

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by defining a Syntax with the X-ENUM extension: http://docs.forgerock.org/en/opendj/2.6.0/admin-guide/index/chap-schema.html#attr-syntax-schema-definition-extensions

First define a `statusSyntax` and then an attribute `status` that uses that syntax.

Comment: The solution although correct, is not an LDAP solution (there are not any that I know of) but rather a solution specific to the OpenDJ implementation.

Comment: I agree the solution is specific to OpenDJ since there are no standard way to do this in LDAP. The question was asked in the context of OpenDJ though ;-)

Comment: Probably repeating, but could this be not done for ldap in particular?

Comment: @inquisitive, are you asking it there is a generic LDAP solution to this ? If so, the answer is no. It is possible to define an LDAP syntax that only accept the 2 values. However, in every LDAP directory server I know of, adding a syntax requires to write code, build and load the extension; with the exception of OpenDJ, where we've added this ability to define syntaxes based on enums (X-ENUM) or regular expressions (X-PATTERN).

Comment: @LudovicPoitou Thanks, that helps, I was probably looking for writing a custom syntax.

Comment: @LudovicPoitou Also, can you please direct me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51357686/openldap-add-open-ldap-defined-attributes-to-custom-class