# OpenLDAP - Add open-ldap defined attributes to custom class

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to create an object class called `request`, it would have fields like `requestID`, `requestType` and `timestamp` (among others).

requestType is string, created like this:

`attributetype ( <some oid> NAME 'requestType' DESC 'the type of the request' EQUALITY caseExactMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.44{250} )`

instead of defining custom attributes `requestID` and `timestamp` I want to use the attributes defined by openldap like [`entryUUID`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4530.txt) and [`createTimestamp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4517), so that I don't have to deal with generating a UUID or the timestamp for the request at the client side, how do I achieve that?

This is how my object class schema definition looks like right now,

`objectclass ( <some oid> NAME 'request' SUP top STRUCTURAL DESC 'request' MUST ( requestType ))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes *entryUUID* and *createTimestamp* are so-called operational attributes which are added to each LDAP entry anyway. No need to add them explicitly in the schema.

However when querying your LDAP entries you have to explicitly list those attribute in your LDAP search request (e.g. at the ldapsearch command-line). Otherwise the OpenLDAP server will not return them.

BTW: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but did you have a look at OpenLDAP's overlay [slapo-accesslog](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-accesslog)?

Comment: Hi, I just had a look at slapo-accesslog, the request I mentioned in the question is more than this, so slapo-accesslog might not help. But I get that I need not add these fields explicitly, and use them (and may be rename them to what I want) in my client side code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set specific values to the `requestID` and `timeStamp` you must define your own attributes, you cannot use the operational attributes `entryUUID` and `createTimestamp`. These attributes are managed by the server and the values are controlled/generated by the server. They are not meant to be used as user data.

You can define attributes that have similar syntax though.